# The Outcome doesnt come out right

Tags: c++, cmath

Okay so I have this code that supposedly gets the balance of a compound interest supposedly the equation goes like this

w(1+x/y)raised to yz

and the code I produced goes
 like this

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;


float power(int x,int y, int z)
{
float pwr, term;
pwr =(y+z);
term = (1.0+x/static_cast<float>(y));
return pwr;
}


float interest(int w, int x, int y, int z, float pwr, float term)
{
float ans;
ans = pow(w*term,pwr);
return ans;
}

main()
{

int w,x,y,z;
float pwr, ans, term;

cout << "\n Enter value for w: ";
cin >> w;
cout << "\n Enter value for x: ";
cin >> x;
cout << "\n Enter value for y: ";
cin >> y;
cout << "\n Enter value for z: ";
cin >> z;

pwr = power(x,y,z);
ans = interest( w, x, y, z,pwr, term);

cout << "\nYour balance is Php "<<ans;




}
```

it runs okay...
but assuming the values given for w x y and z are 5, 2, 4, 2 respectively. the outcome is supposed to be 128.145
but the output after inputing the numbers is 6...
help

Comment: `ans = (w*term,pwr);` - what do you think this does?

Comment: You've just discovered the comma operator =)

Comment: oh crud i forgot to put the pow

Comment: Also `term` is not initialized... And looking at this code I have a suspicion that you should go through a (basic) C++ tutorial

Comment: `ans = pow(w*term,pwr);` invokes *undefined behavior* because `term` is default initialized and therefore has an indeterminate value

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you were missing the functionality for findterm.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;


float power(int x,int y, int z)
{
float pwr;
pwr =(y+z);
return pwr;
}

float findterm(int x, int z)
{
float term;
term = (1.0+x/static_cast<float>(y));
return term;
}

float interest(int w, int x, int y, int z, float pwr, float term)
{
float ans;
ans = (w*term,pwr);
return ans;
}

main()
{

int w,x,y,z;
float pwr, ans, term;

cout << "\n Enter value for w: ";
cin >> w;
cout << "\n Enter value for x: ";
cin >> x;
cout << "\n Enter value for y: ";
cin >> y;
cout << "\n Enter value for z: ";
cin >> z;

pwr = power(x,y,z);
term = findterm(x,z);
ans = interest( w, x, y, z,pwr, term);

cout << "\nYour balance is Php "<<ans;

}
```